# Simple javascript / jquery "on [Escape]" action - how to do it?

Tags: javascript, keydown

I've been mired in documents explaining javascript keydown events for days - and still can't find out how to do this!

What I want:

```
$( 'element' ).on( blur mouseleave ESCAPE, function( event ) {
    do stuff;
}
```

It's trivial, right? I realise I might have to write a little function to create a suitable 'event', but I can't even see what it is I need to do.

Comment: `$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {if (e.keyCode === 27) alert('Esc key pressed.'); });`

Comment: Thanks. Good idea to use keyup instead. I can use this to add a separate function ( if keyup = 27, do the mouseleave function ) but isn't there a more intuitive & less repetitive approach?

Comment: If you want 'more intuitive' you can always write a wrapper that takes a handler that only gets executed on a certain keycodes. But this is the default way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example based on your question and the comment.

```
$('element')
  .on('mouseleave', onMouseleave)
  .on('keyup', onKeyup);

function onMouseleave() { // do stuff; }
function onKeyup(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) onEsc(); 
}
function onEsc() {
  // do stuff; 
  onMouseleave();
}
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! Based on this, I can make a small library of functions to run when various user events occur - which will ultimately solve my keyboard navigation frustrations.